# Emacs/GNUs biff display-time-mode not updating mail

Tags: email, emacs, notifications, gnus, biff

I recently made the switch from OpenSUSE 12.2/KDE to Fedora 19/Gnome; my .emacs has stayed the same. In particular, I am using
    (display-time-mode 1)
On KDE, this worked beautifully to provide me a "mail" update whenever my Fetchmail daemon grabbed new messages. However, now on Gnome, I only get a biff notification when I have just started emacs, or when I re-evaluate my .emacs file. I have tried this in both emacs and emacsclient, and neither seems to automatically provide biff anymore; I'm not sure what's changed (emacs version is probably different, but why would a newer version break this?). Help, please!

Pertinent code from .emacs:

```
;; Clock & Biff display
(setq display-time-24hr-format t)
 ;; display-time-mode mail notification
(defface display-time-mail-face '((t (:background "red")))
  "If display-time-use-mail-icon is non-nil, its background colour is that
      of this face. Should be distinct from mode-line. Note that this does not seem
      to affect display-time-mail-string as claimed.")
(setq
 display-time-mail-file "/var/mail/torys"
 display-time-use-mail-icon t
 display-time-mail-face 'display-time-mail-face)
(display-time-mode 1)
```

GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.2) of 2013-08-14 on buildvm-15.phx2.fedoraproject.org

Comment: Is your mail still being delivered to the same location? I'm guessing it isn't.

Comment: I have updated the spool paths for my new username, so the mail is getting there, and when I open GNUs and refresh, it downloads it all just fine--it just doesn't notify me.

Comment: @tripleee,  you are right; I missed an important line in my .gnus.

Answer (score 0):

Tripleee was correct: although I had fixed most of the paths across my .gnus and .fetchmailrc, I had missed these crucial lines:

```
nnmail-spool-file "/var/mail/[my user]"
display-time-mail-file "/var/mail/[my user]"
```

Obviously, those are the key lines for getting it to work properly.